# What are the naming conventions in C#?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

> There are a few questions on this, but they all seemed to be targeting a specific part of the language;
>
> - [What are the most common naming conventions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228478/what-are-the-most-common-naming-conventions-in-c) - Asking specifically about getters/setters.
> - [C# naming conventions for acronyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109171/c-sharp-naming-conventions) - Asking more specifically about short uppercase suffixes.

I'm just starting out in C# with a friend on a venture to create games for XBOX Live Arcade. I've developed a number of games using ActionScript 2 and 3 but want to start exploring more powerful languages and devices.

I want to ensure that I don't peeve people that I start working with (if I get to that) or even just people on here when I run into trouble and ask a question with seriously disturbing / "incorrect" naming of methods, etc.

I've found it confusing in the example code that I've seen because there seems to be from my current point of view some flaws. I doubt that a flawed naming convention would be used, so I realize that I'm just having trouble understanding.

As far as I can tell so far, there are these conventions:

- `public Type SomeMethod()`
- `private Type SomeMethod()` - no underscore or anything?
- `public static Type SomeMethod()`
- `private static Type _SomeMethod()` - this one just seems odd..
- `public Type someProperty` - switching it up to camel casing for properties?
- `public static Type SomeProperty` - and then going back to pascal casing for static..

In ActionScript 3, I have developed and strictly stick to these conventions:

- `private var _someVar`
- `public var someVar`
- `private function _someMethod()`
- `public function someMethod()`
- `public static var SomeStaticVar`
- `public static function SomeStaticMethod()`
- `public const SOME_CONSTANT`

Is there a complete list of naming conventions with reasoning behind each so that I can get my head around them? The reversal of syntax (i.e. `public Type method()` instead of AS3's `public function method():Type`) is throwing me out enough at the moment that I know I need to keep an eye on how I'm naming things, otherwise I'll forget and develop bad habits, which I'd rather nail and avoid now.

Comment: I don't think there is a single convention -- I tend to see all sorts of different styles used by different coders. The most important thing is to be consistent throughout your code, I think. Pick a convention and stick to it.

Comment: Some Microsoft guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx and some cheat sheet that I find useful:  http://csharpguidelines.codeplex.com

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is the [All-In-One Code Framework Coding Standards](http://www.scribd.com/doc/56782158/All-In-One-Code-Framework-Coding-Standards) from Microsoft which contains a complete set of rules and guidelines. (also used to be available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170305071831/http://1code.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All-In-One%20Code%20Framework%20Coding%20Standards))

> This document describes the coding style guideline for native C++ and .NET (C# and VB.NET) programming used by the Microsoft All-In-One Code Framework project team.

Comment: Have to pay for scribd

Comment: @rolls You can view the document on scribd **or** codeplex for free. If you want to download it then use the codeplex link.

Comment: Thank you I just found that out.

Comment: @Nasreddine Codeplex was killed, link is no longeruseful

Answer (score 58):

The two main Capitalizations are called camelCase and PascalCase.

The basic rules (with lots of variations) are

- Types use PascalCase
- properties and methods always use PascalCase
- public members (fields, consts) use PascalCase
- local variables use camelCase
- parameters use camelCase

And although [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229012%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that "Internal and private fields are not covered by guidelines" there are some clear conventions:

- private fields use camelCase
- private fields that back a property prefix a `_`

Comment: @ Henk. Wat about protected and static fields ?

Comment: _ is forbidden in `Microsoft's` naming convention.

Comment: @Yoda - what version/year? MS was adamant about that when Fx 1 came out but a few yars later backing fields were commonly prefixed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, the [general naming conventions for .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says "DO NOT use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters".

Comment: @Mike, and at the neighbour page for Type Members: "Internal and private fields are not covered by guidelines". My answer refers to what I see being used in practice.

Comment: It appears that the no _ limit has been in since at least [.NET 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045(v=vs.80).aspx).  You will note that it states _These guidelines apply to all identifiers._ and _Do not use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters._  While this document appear to apply only to publicly released libraries, the other links have the same constraints.

Comment: @Trisped Yet MS still uses them in their own [code samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243176.aspx).

Comment: What is the rule about private functions, as opposed to fields/properties?  Are ordinary private functions resigned to PascalCase, camelCase, or an option of either?  ...Is that covered by the second point, I guess?

Answer (score 8):

There are a whole lot of naming conventions advocated by Microsoft for .Net programming. You can read about these [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx).

As a rule of thumb, use PascalCase for public property, method and type name.

For parameters and local variables, use camelCase.

For private fields, choose one: some use camelCase, other prefix _camelCase with an _.

A commonly seen convention is also to name constants with ALLCAPS.

Comment: I guess the all-caps convention is a relict of old coding styles originating in C. This is definitely something you won’t find among standard .NET constants or enumerations.

Comment: I use ALLCAPS for enums and constants in C# still as most of the time I'm using them with interop C++ DLLs

Answer (score 4):

C# prefers PascalCasing for classes, properties, and methods.

As far as I can tell so far, there are these conventions:

- `public Type SomeMethod()` <-- yes
- `private Type SomeMethod()` <-- correct, no underscore
- `public static Type SomeMethod()` <-- correct
- `private static Type _SomeMethod()` <-- this seems odd to me too. underscore should not be there
- `public Type someProperty` <-- no, a public property should be PascalCased (SomeProperty)
- `public static Type SomeProperty` - and then going back to pascal casing for static..

If you are using Visual Studio, or XNA Game Studio (which I think is a fork of Visual Studio),  I highly recommend springing for a ReSharper license (from jetbrains software). They will tell you, in your code editor, how to conform to common C# conventions.

**Addition:**

You should use camelCasing for private fields and method arguments. For private fields, I usually prepend them _withAnUnderscore.