# Calling static method from static method would be thread safe in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a static class which contains methods only and none of them share static fields since i don't have any. I am calling one static method from another static method in the same static class.
Is is thread safe? it is a Asp.Net MVC 4 application.

Example code:

```
public static void RecordHasUserIDOnly(int WebRequestID, int UserID)
{
        _RecordWebRequest(WebRequestID, null, UserID);
}

public static void Record(int WebRequestID, int UserID, int UserLogID)
{
        _RecordWebRequest(WebRequestID, UserLogID, UserID);
}

public static void _RecordWebRequest(int WebRequestID, int? UserLogID,int? UserId )
{
        b_l_webrequest B_L_WebRequest = new b_l_webrequest();
        B_L_WebRequest.rq_id = WebRequestID;
        B_L_WebRequest.log_id = UserLogID;
        B_L_WebRequest.user_id = UserId;
        B_L_WebRequest.rq_time = DateTime.Now;

        PerRequestLevelObjects.Get_Database_Npoco().Insert<b_l_webrequest>(B_L_WebRequest);
}
```

Comment: If this is new code there are more basic problems in it than thread safety. I'm talking about naming convention.

Comment: yes @B0Andrew this is new code. I would like to know about naming convention. thanks

Comment: The naming issues are not 'more basic' than the thread-safety. That's nonsense. For the conventions, see for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8497191/60761).

Answer (score 2):

You do share a static field or property:

```
public static void _RecordWebRequest(int WebRequestID, int? UserLogID,int? UserId )
{
   b_l_webrequest B_L_WebRequest = new b_l_webrequest();
   ...
   PerRequestLevelObjects.Get_Database_Npoco().Insert<b_l_webrequest>(B_L_WebRequest);
}
```

So it all depends on how thread-safe `PerRequestLevelObjects` is.

It has little to do with "calling static method from static method", or in which classes they are. The only issue for thread-safety is shared data.