# Create list of model object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to create a list of my model in Javascript. I'm creating app in ASP.NET MVC

I have a model 'testModel' like:

```
    public string prop1{ get; set; }
    public string prop2{ get; set; }
    public string prop3{ get; set; }
```

and I create `List<testModel>()` and pass it by `jquery.post()`

Here's my ajax call:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: 'POST',
            data: myViewModelList,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (result) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is `myViewModelList`? And what is your POST method? and what is your view?

Comment: result should be json array

Comment: @StephenMuecke myViewModelList is a list of my model which I would like to create in javascript and pass it

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I want to create a model and pass it.

Comment: Show us your controller class. Especially, the called action.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: are you trying to pass your testModel array of objects in the data variable name myViewModelList?

Comment: Javascript array is equivalent to .NET `List<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass JS objects as parameters to ASP.NET MVC actions.
JS array will be properly converted to a `List` of models.

For example, in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Update(List<testModel> list)
{
    // update data
    return Json(true);
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "list": [
            {
                "prop1": "1",
                "prop2": "2",
                "prop3": "3"
            },
            {
                "prop1": "4",
                "prop2": "5",
                "prop3": "6"
            }
        ]
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

It should work fine.

*P.S.* Please, read about naming conventions in C#. For example, [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497103/what-are-the-naming-conventions-in-c). It is difficult to read a code when your class is called `testModel`, and it's public auto-properties are named `prop1`, `prop2` and `prop3`.