# Naming Convention for Model Properties?

Tags: c#, architecture

If you have an int that represents days, what would be the best way for its name:

1. `MinLimitInDays`?
2. `MinLimit`with "in days" as xml doc comment?

or the same with a double:

1. `ProductRevenueInPercentage`
2. `ProductRevenue` with "in percentage" as xml doc comment?

Or would you even create a new class with a specific constructor e.g. `MinLimit(int days)` that has a property int days?

Comment: If you ask 10 devs, you'll get probably 11 opinions on that.

Comment: So there is no best practice? And these opinions are all valid and objectively correct?

Comment: Don't be afraid to use long variable names, it should be as descriptive as possible. Good variable names: `maxDaysInAYear`, `percentageOfStaffComingLate`, `totalDebts`. These names clearly show the intent of the programmer. This applies for properties too.

Comment: None, that I am aware of. All of the proposed have pros and cons and even make sense for one class of properties but not for another. For example "StartDateInGregorianCalendarDate" ... over the top, right? But in an application where you in fact deal with different calendars it could make sense ...

Comment: @RosdiKasim That was my thought as well. But then I remembered why we use `DateTimeOffset` for a variable called `LastSeen` instead of `LastSeenUTCfrom1600long`

Comment: Rules of thumb, the less comments/documentation required the better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497103/what-are-the-naming-conventions-in-c

Comment: "put on hold as primarily opinion-based" -- Isn't architecture normally "primarily opinion based"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) that you should value readability over brevity.

So:

```
int MinLimitInDays = 4;
```

Would be better represented as:

```
int MinimumAmountOfDays = 4;
```

Better yet, save it as a TimeSpan

```
TimeSpan MinimumLimit = TimeSpan.FromDays(4);
```

With everything else, if you're not sure, make it more verbose.

```
double ProductRevenuePercentage;
```

is better than:

```
double ProductRevenue;
```

which could be the overall revenue. Don't be afraid of making properties too long, and don't abbreviate unless the abbreviation is ubiquitous.