# binding observable collection of custom objects containing array

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, expandoobject, dynamicobject

i'm learning wpf and binding and all and i have a gridview and a custom object

i'm trying to bind a list of custom objects to the grid my custom object is designed like this

```
 Public class myObject 
  {
    protected int myInt {get; set;}
    protected ObservableCollection<string> myStrings{get;set;}
    protected double myDouble{get;set}

    public myObject(int aInt, string aString, double aDouble)
   {
    myStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>(); 
    string[] substrings = aString.split('/');
    this.myInt = aInt;


     foreach (string s in substrings)
     {
         myStrings.Add(s);
     }

     this.myDouble = aDouble;
    }

}
```

so i then create an observablecollection of these objects and bind them to the grid

the double, int are displaying just fine in the grid but the array is displaying the pointer, 
i have a column filled with

```
  "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection `1[System.String]"
```

Could anyone help me displaying the content of the observableCollection in the grid like, each item of the collection would get a column.

Thanks by advance !

**SOLUTION I FOUND**

I tried using templates, but it didn't please me so i used ExpandoObjects
I first created a list of dictionaries containing each row of my future grid, then turned them into expando objects using https://theburningmonk.com/2011/05/idictionarystring-object-to-expandoobject-extension-method/ **Big thanks to him for his awesome custom method**

then i just bound the observable collection of ExpandoObjects to my radgridview and TADA i now have my dynamic grid with dynamic objects

Thanks again for your answers i learnt some usefull informations on templates !

Comment: How did plan for this to work? What shall be the Column Header? How to handle different sizes of the Collections? The least I can say is that this does not work out of the box.

Comment: Do you have the same number of item in the myStrings collection for all your myObject items?

Comment: Unrelated: It is recommended to follow the [C# naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497103/what-are-the-naming-conventions-in-c).

Comment: Neither double/int nor strings should be able to display in this case, actually. You marked them as protected. WPF binding requires properties to be "public" to be able to bind to them

Comment: they actually are public in my code just thought this wasn't right for encapsulation and all so when i rewrote my code for this post i made them protected. But reading all of your comments i realized this wont work out. I could just instead of an array of strings declare as many strings as needed, that would do the trick but i wont be satisfied, i'm searching about dynamic objects dunno if this could help me with my issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What looks more appropriate in you case is to use `RowDetailsTemplate` to define a child `DataGrid`/`GridView` to display the Strings collection, displaying the strings collection at the same level as the other properties could be a hard task to do (and doesn't make much sense).
Here a sample of how to define a `DataGrid` within another one (same thing using `GridView`/`ListView`, `DataGrid` looks more appropriate).

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyInt" Binding="{Binding  MyInt}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyDouble" Binding="{Binding  MyDouble}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyStrings}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

MyObject

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyStrings { get; set; }
    public double MyDouble { get; set; }

    public MyObject(int aInt, string aString, double aDouble)
    {
        MyStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        string[] substrings = aString.Split('/');
        this.MyInt = aInt;


        foreach (string s in substrings)
        {
            MyStrings.Add(s);
        }

        this.MyDouble = aDouble;
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, as specified in the comments above the properties should be Public, In order to be able to bind them.

Comment: Also implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be included.

Comment: @ XAMlMAX Indeed