# Proper Property Naming

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

In the contrived example below, which is the proper way to name my "[Nn]ame" property?  It seems that everything in .NET is some form of Pascal case.  Would it be considered "bad form" to use camel case for property names?  I read the [MS guidelines on naming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx), and they say to use Pascal
case.  I really hate Pascal case and it seems like it is ALL that way.

What is the generally agreed upon standard (is it just the MS guide) or does it not matter?  Am I bad if I use camel case here?  TIA.

```
using System;

namespace Properties {
  class Program {
    static void Main() {

      var tester = new Tester();
      tester.Name = "jmquigley";
      tester.name = "another jmquigley";

      tester.Show();
    }
  }

  class Employee {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public void Show() {
      Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}", Name);
      Console.WriteLine("name = {0}", name);
    }
  }

  class Tester : Employee {
  }
}
```

NOTE: I only used inheritance here to see how a property was handled when using it (to see if everything worked just like a field).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127427/common-naming-conventions e.g. Probably this will get closed as duplicate, but it doesn't "matter," as long as you are consistent, but to the extent that most MS developers use the same standards, then this is wrong. Having two properties with the same scope and name (just differing by a case) is confusing anyway.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't use "[Nn]ame" like that in practice.  I just wanted both naming types for discussion purposes, side by side.  I read a bunch of posts and they didn't answer my question so I didn't think it was a dup (but I guess I don't get to decide that, heh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the generally agreed upon
>   standard (is it just the MS guide)

Yes, the generally agreed-upon standard is the Microsoft guidelines.

> or does it not matter?

Your code will run fine without following the guidelines, but I would follow the conventions if:

- You are part of a team
- You are producing code for an employer
- You are producing open-source code
- You want to be able to read others' code online more easily.
- You want to do any of the above in the future

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft guidelines are used throughout the .Net Framework, and supported by tools like StyleCop, FXCop and ReSharper. Using camel case for properties instead of fields will just confuse the majority of C# developers who expect the opposite.

Comment: It confuses me and makes me want to change it so badly.  It's like an itch and I've got to scratch it.

Comment: If it's your own code that nobody else is going to read it doesn't matter what case you use :)

Comment: Number of times that an application you thought would be a one-off is still in use years later, by other developers, or long after the technology is all but dead: Almost all of them. I still have VB6 installed on my machine. God I hate it.

Comment: @jamietre: I meant own code as in stuff you're doing at home in your spare time.

Comment: Well sure... but unless that's all you ever do, I can't imagine using different naming conventions at home :) Anyway, the only thing worse than trying to comprehend someone else's old/bad code, is trying to comprehend your OWN old/bad code. But I guess that is inevitable.

Comment: @jamietre: That's why I recommend using the MS guidelines :)

Comment: Indeed. I really just wanted to complain because at this very moment, I am having to fix something in an 8 year old VB 6 application that is awful, and unfortunately I wrote it. At the time it was brilliant of course.

Comment: @jamietre: :) I feel your pain. Been there before!

Answer (score 1):

The general agreed upon standard is Pascal case.

There are numerous guides on the subject:

1. [Microsoft Naming Guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
2. [IDesign C# Coding Standards](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/download/IDesign%20CSharp%20Coding%20Standard.zip)
3. [Phillips C# Coding Standard](http://www.tiobe.com/content/paperinfo/gemrcsharpcs.pdf)
4. [C# Coding Style Guid](http://www.csharpfriends.com/articles/getarticle.aspx?articleid=336)
5. [CLS Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

I would recommend that you follow the Pascal case guideline if there is *any* possibility that your code will be seen by anybody else.

Answer (score 0):

Camel case is generally the standard way of doing things. Although if you are working on a personal project, or for some other reason have the option of setting the standard yourself then it probably isn't that important.

Answer (score 0):

The wonderful thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from.

Frankly, it doesn't matter much. If you had ReSharper, its default setting would be to PascalCase the Name property, because it is a public property.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can code however you wish... Just be certain that if you don't capitalize everything, every other .NET developer who looks at your code will think it looks strange.

Also, any job you get programming in C# will likely want you to use capitals as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pascal case is dominant in the .NET world.

Nothing forces you to use Pascal case for your own code, but you will end up with a mix of pascal case (framework types) and camel case (your own types). *Inconsistency* is worse than having to use pascal case, imo.

Additionally, if you're working as part of a larger team or if some fellow programmer might need to maintain your code in the future, that is another good reason to conform to the status quo.

Answer (score 0):

Standard way is Pascal Case for Properties and camel case with an underscore for fields.

```
public string Name { get; }
private string _name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way I've seen it in the wild is properties are usually Pascal case. Pascal case tends to be used for properties, methods, and classes.

The important thing to remember about conventions is it's about easing the communication barriers between two people as opposed to personal preferences. Moving over to a world of Pascal case was very weird when I first started C# after initially writing Java, but looking back, I should have adopted the conventions earlier.

Comment: That's where I'm coming from too (the java world).  It seems a little "alien" to have the method and fields with the name conventions.

Comment: If it helps, think of Public Property accessors as more than just public fields. In the base case, when they are just empty get/set, then they are just public fields. But they are more powerful than that; you can code a fair amount of logic into those get/set functions, so they act very similar to methods. That is probably why the convention is to capitalize properties.